# How is nested loop solutions' complexity of tree treversal equals to O(n)

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, nested-loops, traversal

When you're traversing a tree, you're visiting every node just once probably and logically time complexity of it, is O(n).But what if you're traversing using nested loops (2 , 3 nested for loops for example) why time complexity isn't O(n^2) or O(n^3)?I sense that it could be about bounds but,can't be sure due to lack of knowledge.I would really appreciate if someone explains this cleanly.

edit: sorry, I don't have an example code to show.As said in the answer below, I dont know actually too (nor I could find any example code.) , how could one traverse using multiple nested loops.It was just an what if question occured in my mind when I was thinking about that.But the below answer pretty much satisfies my confusion.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "traverse using nested loops".  Can you provide a code example or otherwise add some precision to your description?

Comment: Because there are faster and slower ways to do things?

Comment: If I have a tree data structure and I am traversing it with 3 for loops nested.So, is it being O(n^3)? acording to fact that Im visiting every node just once shouldnt it be O(n)? or its both true and O(n^3) is just and upper bound just as O(n^4). @Odrade

Comment: @raflman - please provide a clear example of actual code (edit it into your question, do not comment it) that your question relates to. As it currently stands you have only very vague unclear descriptions that others will probably not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of your code has nothing to do with the **number** of loops you use. It depends on what exactly these loops are doing.

If you are using 2/3/4/n loops in your tree traversal code in such a way that you visit every node in the tree only once, then your complexity is still O(n), though I'm not sure how in this specific example you could traverse a tree once using multiple nested loops.

If however, you have 2 loops, such that for every iteration of the first loop (every node of the tree), your 2nd inner loop performs another full traversal of the tree, then your complexity would be O(n^2).

Comment: Note: you don't have to visit every node only once. If you visit it two (three, ...) times, it's still `O(n)`

Comment: If you visit every node more than once but a constant factor multiplied by n e.g. 3n, 4n, 5n .. then yes this is still O(n)